# Is it possible to change the layer visibility (eye) icons to be more readable, in Photoshop Elements 11?

Tags: icons, user-interface, layers, photoshop-elements

In previous versions of Photoshop Elements, the eye icon appeared as opened or closed to indicate a layer's visibility. In Photoshop Elements 11, the layer's visibility is only indicated by a diagonal line through the eye icon, which makes it much harder to read at a glance.

Is it possible to change, customize, or replace the eye icons, either to the previous open/closed pair, or to something else that makes the difference between visible and hidden layers more obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [asked this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13878/is-it-possible-to-change-the-layer-visibility-eye-icons-to-be-more-readable-i) on the Graphic Design StackExchange site, and it would seem the answer is no, it's not possible. Oh well.